# SpellChecker in WPF .NET

Tags: .net, wpf

I am trying to implement a "underline\fix while you type spell checker" can anyone point me to some examples.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You don't need to WPF has a built in spell checker.

```
 <TextBox Name="x" SpellCheck.IsEnabled="True" Language="en-us"></TextBox>
```

When a word is misspelled in the textbox it will:

- Underlines the misspelled word in
  red.
- Right clicking the word will
  show a context menu with 
  suggestions.

The spelling suggestions is taken from the dictionary used by Office2007. You don’t need Office 2007 installed as it uses a copy of the dictionary. However, the functionality will be the same.

Answer (score 3):

.NET [Netspell Spellchecker](http://sourceforge.net/projects/netspell/) is a free (open source) Spell Checking library in case you were looking for how others have implemented it.